# Passing entire where clause to native spring jpa @Query

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

Currently I'm unable to know the fields that will be within the SQL where clause (think adhoc) when creating the native SQL in my spring @Query. Therefore I'm passing in the entire where clause.

If I output the SQL to the console and paste it in to my sql editor I'm able to receive a valid resultset.

```
SELECT * FROM lorder WHERE order_id = 1196077
```

Last SQL output to the console was: 
Hibernate:

```
/* dynamic native SQL query */ SELECT
    * 
FROM
    lorder 
WHERE
    ?
and the where clause value being passed in to the @query is:
order_id = 1196077
```

This is what I am currently doing which is not working.

```
@Query(
    value = "SELECT * FROM lorder WHERE :where",
    nativeQuery = true)
List<OrderEntity> listSelected(@Param("where") String where);
```

Not sure if passing the entire where clause is possible but I'm expecting a list. However I'm currently getting an empty collection.

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to achieve, and why you're using a native query instead of a JPQL query. If you're trying to execute a dynamically created query, then use the criteria API, or QueryDSL. That's what they're for. If you want to use a single method to execute several different static queries, just don't do that: it makes it impossible to test the method, to reuse it several times, makes the code less clear and the tests more brittle.

Comment: Thanks JB. I changed this to use Query query = entityManager.createQuery("Select...)

Comment: Check out `JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>` and `Specification<T>` from Spring Data JPA.

Answer (score 6):

Since using the `@Query` annotation you can only use **named parameters** (your `:where`) or **ordinal parameters** (e.g. `?1`, `?2`) of a specific Java-type, it's not possible to inject partial SQL-expressions.

However you could use a **TypedQuery** to add partial SQL to a query:

```
  public List<OrderEntity> getOrdersUsingWhereClause(EntityManager em, String whereClause) {
    TypedQuery<OrderEntity> query = em.createQuery(
        "SELECT o FROM lorders o WHERE " + whereClause,
        OrderEntity.class);
    return query.getResultList();
  }
```

See [https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/parameter#Parameters_vs.*Literals*](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/parameter#Parameters_vs._Literals_)

Comment: I believe the requirement itself hence the answer are vulnerable to sql injection, unless you handle such attack in outer layers

Comment: @Jayr Totally agree. That's the trade-off OP must be aware of: __security__ (threatened by potential sql-injection) VS __flexibility__ (gained by simply injecting user-defined sql-partials). Go ahead and comment the original post by asking for these further requirements worth considering.

Comment: My version passes the entity as a string and uses reflection to get the entity class. There is a limitation however. A whereClause with an embedded semi-colon will fail. For example, whereClause = "description like '%;%'"

Answer (score 0):

The JPA's criteria query gives you more power to control where clause along with many other supported functionalities.

List of functions : https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria

Criteria Queries : https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries

Learn more about criteria query and criteria builder [here](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria)

Comment: Using _Criteria Queries_ is a viable approach which has a **security-benefit** (prohibit SQL injection) but __restricts flexibility__ at runtime by allowing only WHERE-conditions coded at design-time. Super that you provided these links to learn. Proceed and add some code trying to solve the concrete problem asked :-)